# How to click on thumbnail image and open full-size image in a new browser window using MVC3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have researched this and tried many different ways with no success. I have a MVC 3 view that has a list of thumbnail images, I want to click a thumbnail image and open a different full-size image in a new browser window on top of the view. I know this is a simple task but I can not seem to get this to work. Can someone please tell me how to do this in MVC?

Orgbrat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openImage(imageUrl) { 
    window.open(theURL); 
  } 
</script>

<a href="javascript:;" onClick="openImage('image.gif')">
  <img src="image.gif" width="50px"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="thumbnailUrl.jpg" onclick="javascript:window.open(bigImageUrl.jpg)"/>
```